# Strength issue while pick Image from gallery in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, gallery, image-gallery

I know  how to `pickUp` `Image` from the gallery.But the same code is work in my other Application But in my new Application is does not work.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button upload_proof_button;

    Bitmap bitmaps;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    ImageView filename;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        filename = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.filename_textveiw);

        upload_proof_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_proof_button);
        upload_proof_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            try {
                bitmaps = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                if(bitmaps == null){
                    filename.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

and I write permission in `manifest.xml` file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Error Logcat :**

> 07-20 06:16:10.401 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 287K, 13% free 3182K/3640K, paused 2ms,
>   total 2ms 07-20 06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable 07-20
>   06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 442:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
>   (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   07-20 06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 07-20 06:16:10.411
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity 07-20
>   06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 444:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
>   (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   07-20 06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 07-20 06:16:10.411
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal E/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   07-20 06:16:10.411 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 152
>   (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in
>   Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; 07-20 06:16:10.411
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x20 at 0x000c 07-20 06:16:10.721
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling
>   debug mode 0 07-20 06:16:14.441
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
>   07-20 06:16:14.441 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 287:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList
>   (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList; 07-20 06:16:14.441
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 07-20 06:16:15.731
>   12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC
>   freed 270K, 12% free 3281K/3724K, paused 3ms, total 3ms 07-20
>   06:16:15.741 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/dalvikvm:
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 97K, 14% free 3337K/3880K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
>   07-20 06:16:15.741 12940-12940/com.example.softeng.jogifinal
>   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.106MB for 1764372-byte
>   allocation 07-20 06:16:15.751
>   12940-12948/com.example.softeng.jogifinal D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC
>   freed <1K, 10% free 5060K/5604K, paused 5ms, total 5ms

What I have do :

1. try to `clean` the project.
2. try `Invalidate and caches`.
3. Restart Andriod Studio 3 time. But not work..

Any Help be Appreciated ..

Comment: can you check if there is anything in logs when it's not working ?

Comment: @KunalK can this `GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 286K, 13% free 3281K/3740K, paused 2ms, total 2ms` is affect or not ??

Comment: no there should be some warning or error message.

Comment: @KunalK No my logcat is not displaying any error.

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?? i said not WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @AnwarKamal I have both permission. but there is no need ??

Comment: have you tried debugging what you get in onActivityResult ?

Comment: your are reading image from gallery so read permission must be in manifest

Comment: @KunalK I try but it can't go inside the `onActivityResult`.

Comment: in what android version you are testing ?

Comment: @KunalK `Api 19 Samsung Note 3`.

Comment: @KunalK see this error is display `error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg` but I think that is not problem.

Comment: @Ironman i am giving you code of onActivityResult i am using and its working fine

Comment: @AnwarKamal I know in by other Application is work file but in this is work..

Comment: your target and min sdk?

Comment: @AnwarKamal `min` is `15` and `target` is `24`.

Comment: @AnwarKamal not work..

Comment: please share your log

Comment: @JaydeepPatel did you read my question ??

Comment: @Ironman better post your full class

Comment: @LubomirBabev I have update it ..

Comment: @JaydeepPatel That libraray Use for `ImageCopper` in I don't want to add extra `dependency` to my `project`.

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){

                    String picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
            
                }

try this

Comment: @AnwarKamal I try all possible solution of Stackoverflow but none of that is work for me ??

Comment: i am using same code and testing on note 3 for you but it is working fine 
I thing problem is somewhere else in your project not in this code.

Comment: @AnwarKamal ya you are right.

Comment: i will suggest start digging your error in manifest or build file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if your bitmap is `null` to set it to the ImageView. Change to this :

```
if (bitmaps != null) {
    filename.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
} else {
    filename.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the Help.. It's Work.. When I change condition of `==` to `!=` is working fine..

Comment: Hehe no problem. Told ya :P

Comment: Ya.. But I can' t see on `condition`.